# ElasticSearch: Partial/Exact Scoring with edge_ngram & fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, partial, scoring, exact-match

In ElasticSearch I am trying to get correct scoring using edge_ngram with fuzziness. I would like exact matches to have the highest score and sub matches have lesser scores. Below is my setup and scoring results.

```
settings: {
          number_of_shards: 1,
          analysis: {
             filter: {
                ngram_filter: {
                   type: 'edge_ngram',
                   min_gram: 2,
                   max_gram: 20
                }
             },
             analyzer: {
                ngram_analyzer: {
                   type: 'custom',
                   tokenizer: 'standard',
                   filter: [
                      'lowercase',
                      'ngram_filter'
                   ]
                }
             }
          }
       },
    mappings: [{
          name: 'voter',
          _all: {
                'type': 'string',
                'index_analyzer': 'ngram_analyzer',
                'search_analyzer': 'standard'
             },
             properties: {
                last: {
                   type: 'string',
                   required : true,
                   include_in_all: true,
                   term_vector: 'yes',
                   index_analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                   search_analyzer: 'standard'
                },
                first: {
                   type: 'string',
                   required : true,
                   include_in_all: true,
                   term_vector: 'yes',
                   index_analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                   search_analyzer: 'standard'
                },

             }

       }]
```

After doing a POST with first name "Michael" I do a query as below with changes "Michael", "Michae", "Micha", "Mich", "Mic", and "Mi".

```
GET voter/voter/_search
{
 "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "Michael",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My score results are:

```
-"Michael": 0.19535106
-"Michae": 0.2242768
-"Micha": 0.24513611
-"Mich": 0.22340237
-"Mic": 0.21408978
-"Mi": 0.15438235
```

As you can see the score results aren't getting as expected. I would like "Michael" to have the highest score and "Mi" to have the lowest

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not practical to compare scores for different queries (dig into the [lucene scoring function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html) to understand what happens with query normalization).  Also your fuzzy operation is probably confusing things since each bigram is within two edits of each other bigram.    Try removing the fuzziness and repeating your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this problem would be to add raw version of text in your mapping like this

```
                   last: {
                       type: 'string',
                       required : true,
                       include_in_all: true,
                       term_vector: 'yes',
                       index_analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                       search_analyzer: 'standard',
                       "fields": {
                            "raw": { 
                               "type":  "string"  <--- index with standard analyzer
                              }
                          }
                    },
                    first: {
                       type: 'string',
                       required : true,
                       include_in_all: true,
                       term_vector: 'yes',
                       index_analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                       search_analyzer: 'standard',
                       "fields": {
                            "raw": { 
                               "type":  "string"  <--- index with standard analyzer
                              }
                          }
                    },
```

You could also make it **exact** with `index : not_analyzed`

Then you can query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": {
              "query": "Michael",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "prefix_length": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "last.raw": {
              "query": "Michael",
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "first.raw": {
              "query": "Michael",
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Documents that matches more clauses will be scored higher.
You could specify `boost` according to your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fully work. While it does give me a higher score for exact matches it does not handle partial matches scoring wise.