# elasticsearch ngram analyzer return unexpected result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ngram analyzer for indexing and standard analyzer for query.

currently i have indexed multiphone and iphone.

when i search for iphone the score and therefore relevancy of multiphone is higher than iphone.

how should i build query in order to get higher score for iphone?

the query that i execute is

```
"query": {
   "filtered": {
     "query": {
       "multi_match": {
         "query": "iphone",
           "fields": [
               "englishName",
               "aliasName"
            ]
        }
     },
```

what i need is that iphone score be higher than multiphone.

what about performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833781/elasticsearch-partial-exact-scoring-with-edge-ngram-fuzziness/33834855#33834855)

Basically you need to add raw version of the field to your mapping. You could use [keyword analzyer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) with [lowercase filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html?q=lowercase) or you can make it `"index" : "not_analyzed"` or even use default standard analyzer.

Then you do a `bool` query and add a clause for the `exact match` and It will be scored higher.

**EDIT** : **Example**

You could map your englishName field as follow

```
englishName: {
    type: 'string',
    index_analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
    search_analyzer: 'standard',
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed" <--- here
        }
    }
}
```

You could do the same with aliasName
Then your query would look something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "iphone",
            "fields": [
              "englishName",
              "aliasName"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "iphone",
            "fields": [
              "englishName.raw",
              "aliasName.raw"
            ],
            "boost": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*iphone* will be scored higher with this query

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I meant was to index the string as it is rather than analyzing it, sorry about that.

Comment: could you please be more specific by example

Comment: I have update the answer, let me know if you face any issues

Comment: what about using standard index analyzer for raw version?